# Model vs ViewModel, differences and examples

Tags: asp.net

I am confusing between Model and ViewModel, how to use it properly, and the main question, when?
Examples are welcome!

Comment: You're asking an open-ended, and likely opinionated, question - it's difficult to give a straight _universally applicable_ answer.

Comment: I mean, how do you understand these features?

Answer (score 2):

A model is generally more directly tied to how your data is kept (database, services, etc.).

The ViewModel, on the other hand, is concerned with how your data is shown to the user.

For example your model may have characteristics such as the following

```
FirstName 
LastName
```

However, you may opt to express it differently in your ViewModel

```
FullName
```